# How to get service's NodePort programmatically in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I developed two web apps(we call them A and B) and deployed them to k8s. The web app A refers to the images generated by web app B. In previous environment, B has the fixed IP and port which makes it very easier to reach the images hosted on B.

In the K8S environment, I use the service type - NodePort. In that case, the port is randomly generated upon deployment each time.

The question is whether there is a way to fetch B service's node port programmatically from the A Pod. Or is it possible to fix the node port for one service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three answers to your question:

The first is that one should not be destroying the `Service` just because the `Pod`s behind it are redeployed. The `Service` is designed to be the long-lived contract that abstracts over the placement (or count) of the servicing `Pod`s

The second is that if you do wish to have web-app A use a known-to-you `NodePort`, you can put a value in the [nodePort:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.7/#serviceport-v1-core) field of the `ports:` mapping inside the `Service`, and assuming it is not already assigned, kubernetes will defer to your judgement

The third answer is that every `Pod` that runs within the cluster automatically gains an API token for communication with the kubernetes API (it lives in `/run/secrets/kubernetes.io` or similar), so you can ask the API from within the Pods to give you the current value of the Service's nodePort

Comment: Very helpful, Thanks.